# cgroup controller delegation not passing down the hierarchy

Tags: systemd, cgroups, podman

Forgive me if I butcher some terms as the whole cgroup thing is new to me...

Background story is I'm trying to get [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) to run in Rocky Linux 8 and/or 9, which have rootless podman.  I've gotten both OS versions to the same point of mostly working with cgroup v2, but can't figure out what's going on to get it fully working.

Through some configuring (moreso on Rocky 8), I have gotten cgroup controller delegation enabled, but it seems to stop part-way through the cgroup hierarchy.

The important bit of configuring systemd was

```
# /etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/delegate.conf
[Service]
Delegate=cpu cpuset io memory pids
```

Verify that needed controllers are now available:

```bash
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/cgroup.controllers
cpuset cpu io memory pids
```

However, subtree control of the user service does **not** include all these controllers:

```bash
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/cgroup.subtree_control
memory pids
```

Because the terminal that I interact with is under that user service, it does not have the cpu & io controllers delegated down to it:

```bash
$ cat /proc/self/cgroup
0::/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/gnome-terminal-server.service

$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/gnome-terminal-server.service/cgrouop.controllers
memory pids
```

Trying to run `kind create cluster` in this configuration errors out because the necessary controllers are not delegated.

If I manually add those controllers to the user service subtree_control:

```bash
$ echo '+cpuset +cpu +io' > /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service
```

Everything works great.

So my question is - what am  I missing to have this last bit of passing down delegation done automatically?  I'd really rather not have to run that echo command every time I log in.